# Evaluate $\sin^2x = \frac{2+ \sqrt{3}}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate $\sin^2x = \frac{2+ \sqrt{3}}{4}$

Find value of $2x$

I worked it out as such:

$\sin^2x = \frac{2+ \sqrt{3}}{4} \implies \frac{1- \cos 2x}{2} = \frac{2+ \sqrt{3}}{4}$

$2 - 2 \cos 2x = 2 + \sqrt{3}$

$- 2 \cos 2x = + \sqrt{3}$

$ \cos 2x = \frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}$

And $ 2x = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

I was told that the angle $2x$ has another value: $2x = 2\pi - \frac{5\pi}{6} = \frac{7\pi}{6}$

Why is there another value and what is this value for or mean in this question context.

Comment: i edited, it was a typo! thanks!

Comment: $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$. $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: Typesetting tip: `$\implies$` yields $\implies$.

Comment: Write the last but one equation in the classical form $\cos a = \cos b \iff a=b \ \text{or} \ a=-b=2\pi-b \ mod 2\pi$

Comment: Well, given $\alpha\in[-1,1]$, the statement that is actually true is that $$\cos x=\alpha\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\Bbb Z, x=2k\pi+\arccos \alpha\lor x=2k\pi-\arccos \alpha$$ The fact that you've only been asked for two probably means that in this context only the values in some interval are to be considered (I could guess which, but why guess when I can just not know?), which doesn't necessarily save you from having to decide which elements of $\{2k\pi+\arccos \alpha\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}\cup \{2k\pi-\arccos \alpha\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}$ are in the interval.

Comment: Technically there's an infinite number of solutions to the equation, but typically these questions are limited to the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Are you familiar with the unit circle? Generally, equations of the form $\cos x = a$ have two solutions for $x$ on the interval $[0,2\pi)$ as long as $|a| < 1$.

Comment: Equation $\cos 2x=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ does not determine unique value of $2x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there are always two solutions for the equation $\cos x = a$ on $[0,2\pi)$ when $|a|<1$. If $x_1$ is one solution, then $x_2 = 2\pi - x_1$ is another solution. Indeed

$$\cos x_2 = \cos(2\pi - x_1) = \cos(-x_1) = \cos x_1 $$

where the second equality holds since $\cos$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and the third because it's even function.

EDIT: To address the point Prem made in the comments. In your case you are solving $\cos 2x = a$. If it's expected that $2x\in[0,2\pi)$, then you have two solutions. However, if it's expected that $x\in[0,2\pi)$, and therefore $2x\in [0,4\pi)$, there are four solutions instead. The extra two can be obtained by adding $2\pi$ to the first two, i.e. just using periodicity.

Comment: There are 4 Solutions here because it has Square of Sin or Cos of 2x!

Comment: @Prem, yes, but we are really not given any details in what range the solutions are expected, so I answered in general, not solve this particular exercise.

Comment: The given Equation is Square of Sin & when we consider the range given in your Answer, we will get "2 values due to trig" & "2 values due to Sqrt". It is in general. It will be inaccurate to state "OP got 2 Solutions in that range" where that same range has 4 Solutions in total.

Comment: @Prem you missed my point, but it doesn't matter. I edited my answer anyway.

Comment: I did not miss that Point. If we claim a certain range has 2 values, I am claiming that same range has 4 values. No matter what range OP edits into the Question, we "might" end up having 2+2 or 4+4 or 8+8 values. [[ BTW , Thanks for the edit ! I just think OP will benefit from knowing that there are more Solutions in which-ever range we consider ! ]]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you have two solutions is because $\sin^2(x) = \sin^2(2\pi - x)$
therefore both solutions work.

Comment: In general , when we have "trig function of x" , we might get **2 Solutions**. In this case , it is "Square of trig function" or "trig function of 2x" , which means we might get **4 Solutions** total.